# Getting Image Width of Bootstrap Carousel Slides

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to get the width of each image loaded into the carousel in order to float a logo over the image and make some CSS adjustments.  The jQuery used will only grab the width of the first slide, all other slides return a width of 0.  I thought maybe the Bootstrap Carousel is lazy loading the images, but the "load()" function doesn't seem to be reached at all.  How can I get the widths of all of the images?

A fiddle illustrates the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/7SwtW/6/

```
console.log($('.item:eq(0) img').width()); //gets the correct width: 301
console.log($('.item:eq(1) img').width()); //gets 0
console.log($('.item:eq(2) img').width()); //gets 0

$('.item:eq(0) img').load(function () {
    //doesn't get here        
    imgWidth = $(this).width();
    console.log(imgWidth);
});

$('.item:eq(1) img').load(function () {
    //doesn't get here        
    imgWidth = $(this).width();
    console.log(imgWidth);
});

$('.item:eq(2) img').load(function () {
    //doesn't get here        
    imgWidth = $(this).width();
    console.log(imgWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the bootstrap docs provide a way to access the contents of the slide as they are shown:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {

    var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();

    console.log($('.item:eq('+idx+') img').width());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Place each individual function into the content box where you would normally place the text associated with a specific image. Once that image loads it will display the appropriate height. The image is only loaded in it's individual time during the carousal/slider trip.